# Можно ли задать вопрос на SO, чтобы самому ответить на него? Как это правильно сделать?

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы

Хочу задать вопрос, на который знаю ответ, чтобы другие пользователи и гости смогли  в будущем найти ответ на данный вопрос. Можно ли вообще так делать? И если да то как?

Comment: Можно и нужно (:

Comment: @Suvitruf я просто подумал, что это уже будет не StackOverflow, а какой-то личный блог программиста наподобие хабра

Comment: Если вопрос может пригодиться другим, то его стоит публиковать)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, это зависит от вопроса и ответа. Есть шанс, что вопрос даже с ответом могут закрыть.

Comment: @Suvitruf только сейчас заметил соответствующую галочку под кнопкой "Отправить вопрос" :)